# ltrace equivalent for osx?

Tags: linux, macos, dtrace, strace

osx has the really powerful dtrace/ktrace/dtruss tools - however i'm not willing to invest the time necessary to learn dealing with them right now.

what's the easiest way to get the equivalent functionality of linux ltrace (and possibly strace) on OSX?

Answer (score 25):

No answer for ltrace (except perhaps "work out how to use dtrace" :-) ), but for system call tracing  ala strace, dtruss is a pretty good front end to dtrace.

e.g.

```
dtruss df -h     # run and examine the "df -h" command

dtruss -p 1871   # examine PID 1871

dtruss -n tar    # examine all processes called "tar"
```

Answer (score 10):

you don't need to learn dtrace to use it. there are quite a few dtrace scripts that come with OSX.
To see an (incomplete) list:

> man -k dtrace

In your case `dapptrace` might do the job.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest that DTrace is not as complex as you think it is.  I just wrote a two-part tutorial on using DTrace to tune Cocoa applications for the Mac or iPhone, which can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130121085407/http://www.macresearch.org/tuning-cocoa-applications-using-dtrace-writing-scripts) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130411080544/http://www.macresearch.org/tuning-cocoa-applications-using-dtrace-custom-static-probes-and-instruments).  I came into it thinking that DTrace would be extremely difficult to work with, but it turns out to be reasonably straightforward to use.

Comment: both links are dead. Can you please update your post?

Comment: @reto - For now, I've linked to the archived versions of these pages, but I've checked with the old site administrators about why it went offline. I'll see about summarizing the articles in the answer, as well.