# Why doesn't my Qt application present a GUI when executed?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, user-interface

I have been given a C++/C code with a .pro file to compile in Qt (it is a large, messy code, so I would like to use Qt and the .pro file provided).

The code is intended to generate a GUI. I can compile it in Qt without any errors (on both Mac OS X 10.7.5 and Mac OS X 10.8), and I see the executable. However, when I click on it, nothing happens. When I run it the usual way via the command line nothing happens. Here are the run commands I'm trying:

> ./calc.app/Contents/MacOS/calc
>
> exec ./calc.app/Contents/MacOS/calc (this one results in the output: [Process completed]).

In the .pro file (below), I do not see anything that seems to indicate I want a GUI.  However, I read at the Qt help site that the GUI module does not need to be specified in the .pro file because it is included automatically. Perhaps I am misunderstanding something?

Are the any issues with my .pro file?

```
TEMPLATE = app
LANGUAGE = C++
TARGET = calc
VERSION = 3.1.0

CONFIG -= qt
CONFIG += warn_on
CONFIG += debug
#CONFIG += windows
CONFIG += console

DEFINES += IPMGEMPLUGIN
DEFINES += NOPARTICLEARRAY

!win32 {
  DEFINES += __unix
}

GMS_CPP = ../GMS
GMS_H   = $$GMS_CPP

DEPENDPATH +=
DEPENDPATH += .
DEPENDPATH += $$GMS_H

INCLUDEPATH +=
INCLUDEPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += $$GMS_H

QMAKE_LFLAGS +=
OBJECTS_DIR = obj

SOURCES      +=   main.cpp

include($$GMS_CPP/gms.pri)
```

Comment: What does "compile in QT" mean?

Comment: Try with `macx:CONFIG -= app_bundle` and run the resulting binary on a console. That should make sure you see all output, just in case it's a CLI/non-GUI program (the .pro file somewhat suggests that, but one cannot be sure without seeing the code)

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Thanks for your suggestion.  I tried it.  The only output I see is /Users/me/Developer/trunk/standalone/GMS/trunk/build-calc-Qt_4_7_4_gcc-Debug/gmcalc ; exit;
logout

Comment: This question is [being discussed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215808/power-mad-moderators) at meta @LaszloPapp

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. The content of `$$GMS_CPP/gms.pri` and a minimal source file is necessary IMHO.

Comment: What does `dtruss` give you? See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1925978/318716 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/1258481/318716

Comment: In the project (.pro) file, `CONFIG -= qt` tells us this is a non-QT application; it will not be linked against the Qt libraries. `CONFIG += console` suggests that it is a console application, and is not intended to have a GUI.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know anything about Qt, and of course none of us know anything about the specific application you're compiling - so the assistance I can give you may be woefully inaccurate.

However, this sticks out like a sore thumb:

```
#CONFIG += windows
CONFIG += console
```

[A quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=qt%20CONFIG%20%2b=%20console) indicates that Qt *does indeed* support console applications - that is, applications which do not create a GUI, but instead act as console / terminal / command-line tools. This appears to be the case with the one you're working with. Presuming the application even *works*, it likely expects input to be passed to it on the command line, and will produce output of some sort in response - but with this configuration, it will *not* create a GUI.

I recommend contacting the person who gave you this application for further support.

Comment: That option only exists for Windows, so it is irrelevant for Mac. It is a no-op on Mac. Also, please take a look at the qt tagwiki. It discourages the usage of "QT" as QT is Quick Time (different project and brand).

Comment: You're rather missing the point, Laszlo. If the application was not written to create a GUI, then it isn't going to magically gain one by being compiled on a different OS from the one on which it was written. If you have more extensive knowledge of this topic, consider writing your own answer - as I noted straight away, I have no experience here beyond an ability to observe what is in front of my nose.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot write an answer without seeing the source code and the .pri file as requested. It is unlikely though IMO that the OP wants to run a GUI application and he does not even have a GUI application. I mean, that would be a strange mistake to make, wouldn't it? :) That is my last resort to assume. I think this line is just the bad result of a copy/paste, but then again, I will not post an answer until I am sure, but for that I would need to see more.

Comment: Actually, @Laszlo, I strongly suspect that this is not even a programming question - if this wasn't being actively discussed on MSO right now, I would've already migrated it. Imagine downloading an application off the 'Net, one you've never seen before, and compiling it... There's no documentation, and at best a functional description to go with it... How do you know what sort of UI this application will present? You may *assume* that it's a GUI because that's kinda Qt's *forte* - but there's no requirement that this actually be true (and the listing in the question strongly implies it's not).

Comment: Shog9, I believe the OP is trying to take over the codebase, and there might be some programming mistake. I agree that however, this is off-topic as it stands. Not only the source code is not shown, but not even the .pri build system include file. OT: As per Qt's forte: Qt is an application framework, not GUI framework anymore as initially launched. Although, I can somewhat understand people's confusion about that.

Answer (score 1):

`CONFIG -= qt` basically means "The target is [not] a Qt application/library and [does not require] the Qt library and header files."  You should delete that line.  Source: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#config

Also, it couldn't hurt to add `QT += core gui`.  This is normally done for you automatically, but since you're having project file problems it couldn't hurt...  Also, make sure your main.cpp's `main` method ends in `return a.exec();`, and that `a` is a `QApplication` instance (Qt 4.x) or a `QGUIApplication` instance (Qt 5.x).  `main.cpp` should be a short function that creates the main widget or window, shows it, then starts the event loop.

If your project still doesn't work properly, I would highly recommend that you ditch the project file.  In other words, I would download the OS X package for the Qt SDK, create a new project, then import your files into the new project.  After that, I would pluck only the necessary lines from your old .pro file and put them in the new one until it works (specifically, I noticed you have some custom `DEFINES += ...`).  However, all of this advice assumes the fault lies in the project file, not your code. ;-)

Comment: Yes, `CONFIG -= qt` is also a proof for that what the OP posted is in contradiction IMHO. It should give a compilation error, so that had to be removed before even trying to get the application built.